# C++ Builder not running the application after "Run"

Tags: ide, c++builder, c++builder-xe3

I have a strange problem with C++ Builder XE6. Actually, I noticed this problem even from XE3 version. After clicking "Run" my application compiles, but then hour glass appears, waits for some time and nothing. My application does not run. If I press "Run" again I get information like "Project1.exe has crashed"...

The only solution for me is to use project/clean and then "Run" again. Then is works. But yet, it's a waste of time. Does anyone knows what is this about and how to fix it?

Comment: Every other C++ Builder(XE and newer) user out there knows your pain. Don't forget about our other friends `Failed to allocate SAVEmem` and `bcc exited with code 1`. Embarcadero has not managed to fix these crashes in years - I have my doubts as to whether they ever will.

Comment: Either what @HvS says, or one of the DLLs/BPLs required can't be found, or is a DLL/BPL of the wrong version of the compiler (but found "earlier" in the system path).

Comment: yet, strange, after project/clean it works normal... until next compile :)

Comment: You are lucky that cleaning/building makes it work again. I usually have to restart the whole IDE for it to work again. For a while. Rinse and Repeat. I haven't had the time to try XE7, but with XE5 debugging is an exercise in futility and frustration.

Comment: I found it. Disable incremental linking!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Project -> Options -> C++ Compiler -> Advanced

There you will find the option `<Minimum contiguous memory allocation block size (MB)>`.

Probably it's empty. Make it 128. Restart the IDE and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with a simpler(silly) solution.  If you are manually installing your service or making an installer make sure that the service name in your DFM matches the service name that you are writing to the Windows registry.

Answer (score -2):

The 32 bit IDE can only address 2G memory,which gets used up very quickly and no matter how much memory you have installed to no avail.

This is for all C++ Builder compilers.

The only solution is to use Jomitech Twine Compiler, which will compile even larger projects flawlessly.